# Circular slider with scrolling (jquery+css3)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

Make a circular slider with scrolling. http://magart.com.ua/circle/ Tested in Mozilla!

There is a problem if you just refresh the page, everything will be smoothly around. (you will have to scroll and refresh the page to see it). Tested in Mozilla! But if you scroll, roughness will appear. How to solve the problem?

Part of the code:

```
myDiv.scroll(function () { 
    $newh=$('#wrapper_sl').height()+$(this).scrollTop(); //eternal scroll
    $('#wrapper_sl').height($newh); //eternal scroll
    var $nower=(($(this).scrollTop()+$start_pr)/$skorost)+$ugol*8;
    for (var ink=0, len = $kolvo; ink < len; ink++)
    {
    $rad=((ink)*$ugol+$nower);
    $deg=$rad*360/(2*Math.PI)+270;

    $(ImgDiv[ink]).offset({top: Math.cos(($rad))*$size_dug+$smes_y, left: Math.sin(-($rad))*($size_dug)+$smes_x }).css({'transform':'skewX(-'+$deg+'deg) rotateX('+$deg+'deg)'});
    };
});
```

Comment: I actually don't see the issue in Firefox, but in Chrome it's very rough.

Comment: Just refresh the page, and dont scroll. Pictures will align smoothly in a circle... @DevinYoung

Answer (score 3):

try to give some time for css3 transition.

```
transition: all 0.5s;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s;
```

Also note that the eternal scroll part increases the height of wrapper, so after each time you scroll, speed of the rotation increases. Try to keep the height of wrapper unchanged and put scrolltop to 0 after each scroll.

--Edit

I hope this might help you. See demo in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tRkqS/9/embedded/result/)

```
$(function () {
    rotate();
    myDiv.bind('scroll.rot', rotate);
    myDiv.bind('scroll', $.debounce(250, function () {
        $start_pr += $(this).scrollTop();
        $(this).scrollTop(0);
    }));
});

function rotate() {
    $.debounce(250, true, function () {});
    var $nower = (($(this).scrollTop() + $start_pr) / $skorost) + $ugol * 8;
    for (var ink = 0, len = $kolvo; ink < len; ink++) {
        $rad = ((ink) * $ugol + $nower);
        $deg = $rad * 360 / (2 * Math.PI) + 270;

        $('#info').html(
            '$rad: ' + $rad +
            '<br/>$deg: ' + $deg);

        $(ImgDiv[ink]).offset({
            top: Math.cos(($rad)) * $size_dug + $smes_y,
            left: Math.sin(-($rad)) * ($size_dug) + $smes_x
        }).css({
            'transform': 'skewX(-' + $deg + 'deg) rotateX(' + $deg + 'deg)'
        });
    };
}
```

and here is the source in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tRkqS/9/)

Comment: Yes =( But that was my best idea/solution. How can I reset the scroll, but keep the same position ?)

Comment: scroll resolved) Thanks! but still jumping and... discrepancy... =(

Comment: Oh... another problem... I set to blocks "position:absolute" and replaced "offset" to "css" and it stop jumping =) BUT... I cant scroll when I over blocks... =((((((((((((((((((((((((((((